# ActionScript 3.0 How do I make it once you click a object it goes to next scene?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs6

I am making a simple flash game. How would I make the user to go the next scene when the zombie is clicked?

[image]

Comment: asking for code, nothing to show for, voted down.

Comment: You confirm what I said and show a very low level of language. This question should be removed shortly.

Comment: What have you tried?  All that should be required is a click listener that calls `nextScene()`

Comment: I don't get how this is not enough to get help.... I clearly said "When I click the zombie it goes to the next scene" how much more information do you need?

Answer (score 1):

Create a symbol out of the zombie, call it whatever you want. Then write this code:

```
yourZombieName.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickZombie);

function clickZombie(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop(1, "yourSceneName");
}
```